# How can I include my credentials in the URL if the username contains a forward slash?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url

I am wanting to include my username and password in my url like so, `http://username:password@website/path/to/page.aspx`

However my username contains the slash for the domain. Like: `domain\user`

How can I still pass my credentials through the url when this is the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urlencode it, e.g. `%5C` will be treated as a \

Comment: Thanks! It's still prompting me for a username and password but that's a different problem.

Comment: For me it was the "@" character that led to the same error. Thanks very much for pointing to `urlencode`.